# Error in java String to Date

Tags: java, string, date

I want to transform that `String dateStr= "2013-12-02 14:02:25"` to a date.

The solution is quiet simple, but I didn't obtain the right output.

The code is:

```
try {
Date thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(dateStr);                  System.out.println(thedate);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the output was: `Sun Dec 02 14:02:25 GMT+03:00 2013`

**UPDATE:**

What I want is to get the same format as the string.

Comment: And where is the problem? The output is correct ...

Comment: Tell us how you want the output to be, and - more importantly - what you do to get that output. Just printing the date, without a formatter, is asking for disappointment.

Comment: What did you expect? Seems good to me.

Comment: str and dateStr are two different varible

Comment: Purpose of `Date` object is to hold date, not to print it in specified format (especially when it has only one `toString()` method which can print date in only one format). To produce string that will represent date in specified format use `SimpleDateFormat#format(Date)`.

Comment: If you want the output string in exact same format, then why go through the process of converting to date and then converting back to string again? Why not just use the original string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(thedate));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code formats the date correctly. It gets a `String` and parse it to `Date`. When you print a `Date`, java uses [`Date.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) method.

If you want to print it in a specific format, you need to use another (or same if the patterns are same) `SimpleDateFormat` and call `format` method.

Comment: I was about to write same ans

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this:

```
String str = "2013-12-02 14:02:25";
    try {
        Date thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(str);
        System.out.println(thedate);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(thedate);
        System.out.println("-->"+cal.get(Calendar.DATE)+"::"+(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Search.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

And output was:
-->2::12:2013

Is this what you were looking for ?

Comment: Why time zone? I need the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` as an output.

Comment: You were getting Sunday and I am getting Monday -- hence check the time zone respectively...Also, edited the answer if you want to print the date. Use a calendar object and print the date however you want to

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get out put in same format, just `format` your out put using your `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
    SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date=df.parse("2013-12-02 14:02:25");
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
SimpleDateFormat df = nnew SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = df.parse("2013-12-02 14:02:25");
String formattedDate = df.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this simple code:**

```
String date_time= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
```